# How to verify that text is present on webpage or not with NUnit and C#

Tags: c#, string, unit-testing, nunit

I'm trying to verify text availability on login page of application.

How can I do that?

Using following code I'm able to verify text present or not however I'm stuck to print text against each condition so if text is wrong then test case should get failed.

```
public void Readcontent()
{
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        // string Test = "By logging on you can Ask the our experts your questions by email....";
        string Test;
        string url = "https://sampleweb.com";
        string content = client.DownloadString(url);
        if (content.Contains("XYZ"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Expected Text found here: ");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Expected Text NOT found here: ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine(content);
}
```

Comment: Do you really mean you want to test content as rendered on a web page generated by your back-end?  In that case you may need to look at browser-based javascript unit testing frameworks. Try this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh404088.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: NUnit is a unit-testing framework. It does not have any specific features for UI or web application testing. Are you using some browser automation framework like selenium?

Comment: Yes mike z i'm using selenium framework

Comment: As far as I know, Selenium is not a framework. It's a tool. A framework would be something like NUnit, JUnit, Specflow, Cucumber.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NUnit has class [`StringAssert`](https://docs.nunit.org/2.2.6/stringAssert.html) for string assertions. The class has method `Contains`:

```
[Test]
public void DownloadStringTest()
{
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        string url = "https://sampleweb.com";
        string content = client.DownloadString(url);
        StringAssert.Contains("XYZ", content, "Expected Text NOT found");
    }
}
```

`StringAssert` also has `StartsWith`, `EndsWith` and `AreEqualIgnoringCase` methods.

Answer (score 3):

I'm interpreting your question as "How do I get the test to fail when the content.Contains("XYZ") is false?". To do this you need to add an assertion.

```
Assert.That(actual, Contains.Substring(expected), "Error message");
```

And in your code:

```
[Test]
public void Readcontent()   
{
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        string url = "https://sampleweb.com";
        string content = client.DownloadString(url);
        Assert.That(content, Contains.Substring("XYZ"), "String not found in entire page content.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what has already been said, we use Console.Writeline only for debugging purposes (although not the best approach for debugging your code) and should be ideally removed once code is stable. Any validation should be made through Assert methods and/or custom validation methods in your test automation framework using Assert.